# Vmstateevent invalid json error installing docker on mac Sierra

Tags: macos, docker

I am new to Docker. So please pardon if the question appears fundamental.
I am trying to install Docker (version - 1.12.0-a build :11213) on a Mac OS Sierra version 10.12.1. However I see that the Docker service is quitting randomly with the following error -

```
Fatal Error
vmstateevent invalid json
```

Has anyone got this error? How to fix it?

Comment: https://get.docker.com/ use this script to install docker

Answer (score 0):

I tried multiple installers of Docker and the combination that worked for me was -
Sierra OS 10.12.1 and 
Docker version 1.12.6